# Execute a node js app file and store result in variable in Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

So I've been searching everywhere and couldn't find a proper example that can execute a node js app file from Python, and after execution, stores the result in a varable in python.

This is because I don't want to transfer my whole source code from Py to Js; plus I prefer Python better.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven´t used it but as you ask for 'any help' here it goes: http://sweetme.at/2014/02/17/a-simple-approach-to-execute-a-node.js-script-from-python/

Comment: note to the downvoters: the sheer amount of doc about how to call python from node makes somewhat difficult finding how to call node from python

Comment: why not rewrite the entire thing in JS? instead of doing exactly that but still executing it via python?

Comment: You could try subprocess module in Python if your js app is command line based. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: You have to write your node app with proper routes and make calls in python using requests, once you retrive data as json you can store what ever data you like in the variable.

Comment: @Luke_ because my py code is HUGE, it'd be a hassle but if last resort then yea, but hence why this question for some clarity

Answer (score 0):

The format of the Python and NodeJs variables being not quite the same, it is not possible to simply caste a variable from one language to the other...

Nevertheless, I have some ideas :

- Use a file as a buffer (write the result with js in the file, then read it with Python)
- Use a key-value database, such as [Redis](https://redis.io/) or an asynchronous message queue, such as [RabbitMq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).
- Use low-level modules to make a gateway in C / C++. https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html (Python) + https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp (NodeJs). This solution being nevertheless a bad idea (I think).
- You can also try to create separate modules (each in a language) and have a real micro-component approach. This would be the best approach.

Comment: Yea, the only simple way I thought of was using a `.txt` file to write and read across the programs, but wondered of a better way, which may be your last bulletpoint of **creating separate modules** which I'm trying now